# Simplify execution based on variable and return value to dict

Tags: ansible

Imagine this dict:

```yaml
my_var:
  one_key:
    string: good
    environment: Acceptance
  two_key:
    string: great
    environment: Production
  three_key:
    string: woow
    environment: Production
  four_key:
    string: true
    environment: Else
```

Per 'Production' and 'non production' environment, a specific command needs to be executed only once.
The return value of that command, must be appended to all the correct dict keys/values, based on the environment of course.

E.g. when there are 5 items with environment 'Production' in the dict, execute a command only once, and then append that return value to all 5 dict key/values.
When there is no Production environment described, then simply do not execute the task.

I currently solve this by this piece of code, which isn't DRY at all.
I believe there is a cleaner approach to this use case.

```yaml
- name: loop over the dict and create a 'list' of which is prod and non prod
  set_fact:
    non_prod: >-
      {{ non_prod | default('') }} +
      {{ item.value.environment != 'Production' }}
    prod: >-
      {{ prod | default('') }} +
      {{ item.value.environment == 'Production' }}
  loop: "{{ my_var | dict2items }}"

- name: set state for env execution
  set_fact:
    non_prod: "{{ 'True' in non_prod }}"
    prod: "{{ 'True' in prod }}"

- name: execute command non prod
  shell: echo hi
  register: non_prod_execution
  when: non_prod

- name: execute command prod
  shell: echo hi
  register: prod_execution
  when: prod

# here should follow code where I add the value to the dict with 2 separate tasks
# to save lines code, I've redacted those lines of code, since I believe the issue at hand is clear
```

Comment: `prod:  "{{ my_var | dict2items | map(attribute='value') | selectattr('environment','eq','Production') | length > 0 }}"` and `non_prod:  "{{ my_var | dict2items | map(attribute='value') | selectattr('environment','ne','Production') | length > 0 }}"` would at least make the two first tasks lighter and save you a loop

Comment: What are you looking for exactly, DRY the existing code or have that "_part where I add the value to the dict with 2 seperate tasks_"?

Comment: DRY the code. As described, I 'solved' the 'dict with 2 separate tasks' part. But that isn't DRY as well. I believe the issue at hand is clear, so adding more lines of code would not have any added value. Title also suggests simplifying.

Comment: Yes that part was clear indeed, but adding the fact that you wanted to do X with the result of the command and adding that comment in the code made me wonder. Maybe you should have kept that information aside, to not distract for your question goal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could construct a list of dictionaries for the environments with all the needed information, e.g.

```yaml
environments:
  - name: prod
    command: echo 'hi prod'
    execute: >-
      {{ 
        my_var 
          | dict2items 
          | map(attribute='value') 
          | selectattr('environment','eq','Production') 
          | length > 0 
      }}
  - name: non_prod
    command: echo 'hi non-prod'
    execute: >-
      {{ 
        my_var 
          | dict2items 
          | map(attribute='value') 
          | rejectattr('environment','eq','Production') 
          | length > 0 
      }}
```

Then use that right away in your command.

---

Given the tasks

```yaml
- command: "{{ item.command }}" 
  loop: "{{ environments }}"    
  when: item.execute
  register: command
  loop_control:
    label: "{{ item.name }}"
  vars:
    environments:
      - name: prod
        command: echo 'hi prod'
        execute: >-
          {{ 
            my_var 
              | dict2items 
              | map(attribute='value') 
              | selectattr('environment','eq','Production') 
              | length > 0 
          }}
      - name: non_prod
        command: echo 'hi non-prod'
        execute: >-
          {{ 
            my_var 
              | dict2items 
              | map(attribute='value') 
              | rejectattr('environment','eq','Production') 
              | length > 0 
          }}
   
- debug:
    msg: "command result is `{{ item.stdout }}` for `{{ item.item.name }}`"
  loop: "{{ command.results }}"
  when: item is not skipped
  loop_control:
    label: "{{ item.item.name }}"
```

This would yield:

```
TASK [command] *************************************************************
changed: [localhost] => (item=prod)
changed: [localhost] => (item=non_prod)

TASK [debug] ***************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=prod) => 
  msg: command result is `hi prod` for `prod`
ok: [localhost] => (item=non_prod) => 
  msg: command result is `hi non-prod` for `non_prod`
```

Comment: I'm love this answer. I'll test it out in a couple of hours, thanks!

Comment: Ansible fails at my side due to error: 
"object of type 'generator' has no len()"... must be something with the vars I've setup...

Comment: Nope, that's an the usual generator error on 'old' versions of Ansible, your `selectattr` and `rejectattr` are giving you generator that are not cast back as lists, when it does it on my 'newer' Ansible version

Comment: The fix: throw a `| list` between the `selectattr` and `rejectattr` and the `length` filters.

Comment: FYI: using Ansible v2.9

Comment: Yes, it runs without errors when applying `| list`. Thanks!